# PHP filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') returns null?

Tags: php, filter-input

Why does this line return `null` in my live server?

```
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD');
```

The live server is **php5.5.9**

Have I missed something?

I thought it is used to replace the global method below?

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

some of the code,

```
public function __construct()
    {
        // Construct other generic data.
        $this->clientRequestMethod = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'method'); // such as list, add, update, etc
        $this->clientPostMethod = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'method'); // such as update
        $this->serverRequestMethod = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD'); //such as get or post
    }


    public function processEntry()
    {

        // Determine the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] whether it is post or get.
        if ($this->serverRequestMethod === 'POST' && $this->clientPostMethod != null) 
        {
            $this->processPost();
        }
        else if($this->serverRequestMethod === 'GET' && $this->clientRequestMethod != null) 
        {
            $this->processRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're not applying a filter, why use `filter_input()` at all?

Comment: [Doc says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) it returns "`NULL` if the [...] variable is not set", also see [this comment](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#77307)

Comment: He has set the variable name to `'REQUEST_METHOD'`, and filtering is optional, so I am also curious why this doesn't work

Comment: check for var first

         if (filter_has_var(INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD"))

Comment: Using this: `$res = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD');` returns 'GET' into `$res` for a `GET` request. PHP 5.5, not sure which sub-release.

Comment: `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD');` is what I'm using...

Comment: @tealou ...and where are you putting the result?

Comment: @MikeW what do you mean? I put in php file of course?

Comment: Your code snippet is a function call that returns a value. It works - I tested it. In the snippet you're not storing the return value. You haven't posted enough of the surrounding code to see what you're doing. You also haven't indicated why you think the function returns null. Without some clarification I don't think there's much more we can do.

Comment: @MikeW I just want to store the date into a variable. Please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: guessing - are you sure you are running it through a server (i.e. php-cli has no `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`), test if it is set before applying the filter

Comment: @birdspider yes it is running through the server.

Comment: @birdspider I get the data if I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` but not `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD')`

Comment: @tealou I can't reproduce your problem. Whenever I run that line I get the expected data. I still don't understand why you're using `filter_input()` with no filter. Why not just use the `$_SERVER[]` variable?

Comment: @MikeW yes I have to fall back to `$_SERVER[]` that's my solution.

Comment: @MikeW what do you mean `with no filter`? isn't `filter_input()` a filter?

Comment: this might be a long standing php bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49184 - could not find a reference for it beeing fixed

Comment: I use the PHP `filter_*()` functions a lot, but always with explicitly defined  filters.I'd assumed that with no filter specification PHP would simply return unfiltered data.  I checked the manual. If you omit the filter specification (the third and fourth arguments to `filter_input()`) PHP uses a default filter configured in `PHP.INI` or `.htaccess`.   If your environment defines some default filter that blocks `GET` or `POST` then you'll see the result you're getting. I suggest you try `filter_input()` with a specific filter specification and see what you get.

Comment: @birdspider The code works on my development system: PHP 5.5.15.

Comment: @MikeW well how do the 2 systems differ ? (setup/config wise)

Comment: @MikeW ah sorry confused you with the OP Author

Answer (score 26):

So the problem/bug is this:

**filter_input()** doesn't work with **INPUT_SERVER** or **INPUT_ENV** when you use **FASTCGI**

The bug has been known for years and I found nothing saying it was addressed. I found several work-arounds but no complete solution so I plopped the best work-around into this helper function for a project-wide solution. To provide some level of security and avoid train wrecks, the function falls back to filter_var() where filter_input() fails. It uses the same format as the native filter_input() function for easy integration into projects and easy future removal should the bug ever be fixed.

```
function filter_input_fix ($type, $variable_name, $filter = FILTER_DEFAULT, $options = NULL )
{
    $checkTypes =[
        INPUT_GET,
        INPUT_POST,
        INPUT_COOKIE
    ];

    if ($options === NULL) {
        // No idea if this should be here or not
        // Maybe someone could let me know if this should be removed?
        $options = FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE;
    }

    if (in_array($type, $checkTypes) || filter_has_var($type, $variable_name)) {
        return filter_input($type, $variable_name, $filter, $options);
    } else if ($type == INPUT_SERVER && isset($_SERVER[$variable_name])) {
        return filter_var($_SERVER[$variable_name], $filter, $options);
    } else if ($type == INPUT_ENV && isset($_ENV[$variable_name])) {
        return filter_var($_ENV[$variable_name], $filter, $options);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

This seems the best solution. Please let me know if it contains errors that might cause issues.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem where it was working on my local machine (OSX Mavericks, PHP version 5.4.24) and not on my live server (Cent OS 5). I upgraded the server from 5.3.9 to 5.5.15 (and added the mb and mcrypt functions although that's probably irrelevant) and now it works.

This probably isn't helpful if you're on a shared host but you could ask them if they can rebuild PHP/Apache.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue in my XAMPP localhost as well and was looking for solutions madly. What I ended up with, it is a known PHP bug for this function if you are running the PHP in FCGI mode (FCGI/PHP 5.4 in my case). I was confirmed going through this [link.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49184)

The workaround I used is to `filter_var($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` but this is not an alternative of `filter_input`. `filter_input` is more secure.

Comment: I don't think it matters if a PHP script is run as an AJAX request or normal page load. In any case the $_SERVER or $_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST act as same. So in PHP scripts that you are calling via AJAX, you can use filter_input for POST/GET and filter_var for $_SERVER.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm sorry. I had an error in my script and that's why it seemed like I couldn't access the POST data. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 5):

I solve it changing my `php.ini` from:

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

To:

```
variables_order = "GPCSE"
```

By default PHP wasn't registering the environment variables, so this change enabled them. The interesting is that the `INPUT_SERVER` variables came back to work too!

Just two addiotional informations, i am using PHP 7.0.13 and as said in other answers, this issue is related to a [PHP bug](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php#77307).

Another option is use the following:

```
filter_var(getenv('REQUEST_METHOD'));
```

Comment: In my case it was enough to set `variables_order = "GPCS"` instead of default `EGPCS`. Anyway, I wish I had found this answer a few days ago... This definitely deserves upvoting!

Answer (score 4):

FastCGI seems to cause strange side-effects with unexpected null values when using INPUT_SERVER and INPUT_ENV with this function. You can use this code to see if it affects your server.

If you want to be on the safe side, using the superglobal $_SERVER and $*ENV variables will always work. You can still use the filter** functions for Get/Post/Cookie without a problem, which is the important part!

Source: http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php#77307

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution was to change **filter_input** to **filter_var** :

With filter_input (not working on a Siteground shared hosting):

```
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI')
```

With filter_var (now it works on Siteground)

```
filter_var($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem affects Apache + fcgid + php-cgi 8.1.9 too.

It't caused by auto_globals_jit enabled (default) . When disabled (in php.ini on php startup), filter_input(INPUT_SERVER) works correctly.