# filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'DOCUMENT_ROOT'); returns null

Tags: php, xdebug, filter-input

My site is hosted on a shared host. I’m trying to setup a new development environment (when I say new, I mean that it doesn’t look like any of my previous development environment which ranges from things like a single Notepad++ to “easy” server solutions like WAMP/XAMPP … yet I’m a C#/.NET development so php is more something I casually use at home ...)

My new environment so far has:

- Windows 10 (because that’s what I use at home)
- PhpStorm.
- Php 7.3.3 VC15 x64 Thread Safe unzipped somewhere on my my hard drive.
- php.exe refered as interpreter in PhpStorm
- php_xdebug-2.7.0-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll set has debugged in php.ini

In my php code I have

```
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'DOCUMENT_ROOT');
```

It returns null (or something that is empty).

When I paste it in the terminal is says:

> 'filter_input' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Well, maybe that’s the type of terminal I’m expecting but the fact that it returns null is a problem.

What should I change so that it returns the same value as in my online environment?

I have tried solutions from [PHP filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232975/php-filter-inputinput-server-request-method-returns-null)
including adding `variables_order = "GPCSE"` to php.ini, but it didn’t solve the problem.

Writing `filter_var(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'));` instead but it didn’t solve the problem ...

I want to code for my online environment not to adapt my code to my development environment.

---

**Further test 1**

Running code

```
var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'));

if($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] === '')
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../');

var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'));
```

1st var_dump shows correct value.
2nd var_dump shows correct value.
3rd var_dump shows string(0) "".
I'm not quite sure how $_SERVER and INPUT_SERVER are related though.

Answer (score 2):

This will see if your server can parse the correct information from INPUT_SERVER and INPUT_ENV. If the first var_dump does not show the "DOCUMENT_ROOT" variable, then the filter_input function won't either.

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);
foreach ( array_keys($_SERVER) as $b ) {
    var_dump($b, filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, $b));
}
echo '<hr>';
var_dump($_ENV);
foreach ( array_keys($_ENV) as $b ) {
    var_dump($b, filter_input(INPUT_ENV, $b));
}
?>
```

Comment: In the output of first loop, I see a key named "DOCUMENT_ROOT" but its value is null.
Can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: What is the output of the first var_dump($_SERVER) command? Also, was the code ran via a HTML page or from the CLI? If ran from the CLI, then the DOCUMENT_ROOT would be blank, as that is populated by the web server.

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) is an array containing all kind of string values, few of them are empty, though document DOCUMENT_ROOT is. I assume they're supposed to match DOCUMENT_ROOT value from filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, ...) but they don't seem too as here most are empty.
The page is loaded by clicking on the debug button of PhpStorm (of shift+F9), as a .php file.

Comment: I'm not sure $_SERVER and INPUT_SERVER are related but I just added "Further test 1" to the question.

Comment: The "DOCUMENT_ROOT" value is set when you access the PHP page via a webserver, either Apache or IIS. If you are accessing via the command line interface, then DOCUMENT_ROOT hasn't been set and as such, will be empty.

They are related in the same way that $_GET and INPUT_GET is.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood so far, I was hoping that PhpStorm debugging would "emulate" a server as some IDEs do...
I don't know better "how $_GET and INPUT_GET are related" ... I would have thought those were kind of synonyms or one accessed data from the other, though I've never done any deep check about that.

Comment: Well actually: "PhpStorm has a built-in web server that can be used to preview and debug your application. This server is always running and does not require any manual configuration. All the project files are served on the built-in server with the root URL " ... from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Here some way I found:

Apparently, when you click on the debug button, PhpStorm does not run PHP scripts as if they were accessed via a server, hence some values like DOCUMENT_ROOT are not filled.

However, when accessing to http://localhost:63342/[path]/[filename]  , DOCUMENT_ROOT indeed contains the expected value.

Note: using localhost (or other names) may require editing \Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts file.

I have also set a "server" in PhpStorm (Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers ) on localhost:80 but this one seems ineffective and unrelated, you probably don't need it, not sure.

EDIT: I just realised this is actually only a partial way around because if I use this, debug seem ineffective, breakpoints are not triggered.