# filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI' ) returning NULL

Tags: php

**Issue:** filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI' ) returning NULL unlike $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

**Any idea how I can fix this?** I'm assuming this is an issue on the server.

**Example:** http://someurl.com/

Returns string(1) "/"

```
var_dump( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Returns NULL

```
var_dump( filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI' ) );
```

Same issue occurs with

```
filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name' );
```

I'm using the following as a workaround:

```
filter_var( $_POST[$name], $filter ); // $filter is a reference in the function I'm using
filter_var( $_SERVER[$name], $filter );
filter_var( $_GET[$name], $filter );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was posted on https://php.net As suggested, you should use the $_SERVER or $_POST var

> FastCGI seems to cause strange side-effects with unexpected null values when using INPUT_SERVER and INPUT_ENV with this function. You can use this code to see if it affects your server:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);
foreach ( array_keys($_SERVER) as $b ) {
    var_dump($b, filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, $b));
}
echo '<hr>';
var_dump($_ENV);
foreach ( array_keys($_ENV) as $b ) {
    var_dump($b, filter_input(INPUT_ENV, $b));
}
?>
```

> If you want to be on the safe side, using the superglobal $_SERVER and $_ENV variables will always work. You can still use the filter_* functions for Get/Post/Cookie without a problem, which is the important part!

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently just using `filter_var($_POST or $_SERVER ...` to ensure the data returned is safe (stripped of harmful data that could be passed through it)

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is already old, but I just wasted few days to figure out how to resolve the same problem (I couldn't change the way how `filter_input` is used, as it was part of the external library).

The original answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40699311/1587330 and it seems that it's enough to change `variables_order` setting in php.ini to `GPCSE` or `GPCS`.